# What are the improvements of Flask compared with traditional MAC?

Tags: selinux

I know that traditional MAC has limitations, like that it provides poor support for data and application integrity, separation of duty, and least privilege requirements. So NSA and SCC developed a flexible MAC architecture called Flask to overcome the limitations of traditional MAC. Could someone explain what improvements Flask has made? Thank you!